# Tcl S960 not booting

Tags: root-access, boot

My tcl s960 didnt come with the playstore and some essential google services to make some apps work, while trying to fix that i had to root the phone and mistakenly deleted frameworks from system folder, in root and the android has been unable to boot, it keeps loading and loading, any help would be appreciated.
I alread did the wipe data/factory reset via power button and volume + up key, it still didnt work.. os is 4.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the phone won't bring the framework back. You need to flash a stock firmware to solve the problem.

Download the ROM from [here](http://www.needrom.com/download/tcl-s960-idol-x/). Gapps (Google apps) included and rooted. Use [SP Flashtool](http://spflashtool.com/) for flashing. MTK phones are easy to flash.